# How to read in data array return from ajax for google chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

```
var e = $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo $template->get_template_dir('ajax',DIR_WS_TEMPLATES, $current_page_base,'ajax'); ?>/survey_save.php",
  data: str
}).done(function(data) {
  alert("Survey has been saved."+data);
  $('#form').hide();

      $('#results').show();
  // data array for google chart
  var e = [["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]];
        return e;
    });

google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);        

function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(e);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
  }
}
```

So the code above will return the data array as JSON.  I need to either return it as an array or convert the JSON to an array format.  How could I do that?  When trying to call the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation:

Pass AJAX request and get response data in JSON using mysql query. Feed response data to chart function.

In short, you need to get array values -> convert into JSON and give those values to google chart irrespective whether you need mysql or not. Modify code according to your requirement.

## Client side main php

```
<script>
    drawLineChart('<?php echo strtolower($chartType); ?>');
</script>
```

## Client side function php

```
function drawLineChart(chartType, chartTitle) {
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(lineChartData);

    function lineChartData() {
        var lineChartJsonData = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<?php echo $server_script_path; ?>",
            data: { id1: chartType, id2: "Chart" },
            dataType:"json",
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function(data) {
            },
        }).responseText;

        var options;
        options = {
            title: chartTitle,
            width: '390',
            height: '300',
            vAxis: {title: '<title>'},
        };

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(($.parseJSON(lineChartJsonData)));
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartType));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

## Server side php file

```
if ($_GET['id1'] != "" && $_GET['id2'] == "Chart") {

    // Chart type
    $chartType = explode('-', $_GET['id1'])[1];

    $sql = "<mysql query>";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $table = array();
    $rows = array();
    $rows[] = array('<column1>', '<column2>');
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = array('<rows>', '<rows>');
    }
    $table = $rows;
    echo json_encode($table);
}
```

## Live chart (my array data)

[image]

Comment: So how do I convert   [["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]]; to json?  
Do I write columns array('Element', 'Density', '{role:"style"}')
and row array('Copper','8.94','#b87333'); ...

I guess the unusual element is having the HTML added.

Comment: I couldn't figure out your exact requirement but as an answer given, values should be JSON format with 3 columns and X rows with 3 elements (or whatever no. of column/row you need). Got it?

Comment: I meant the CSS added.  I could not find an example of json with css for google charts.  I will try it!